# Fill multiple select boxes with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have got the following database table (there is more data in the database though, this is not all!):

```
catid   value   description
0        350     350 euro
0        500     500 euro
0        650     650 euro
1        0       No
1        1       Yes
```

With the help of PHP and json_encode() i'm creating a JSON string of this table:

```
jQuery171024539993586950004_1349776890005([{"0":"0","catid":"0","1":"350","value":"350","2":"350 euro","description":"350 euro"},{"0":"0","catid":"0","1":"500","value":"500","2":"500 euro","description":"500 euro"},{"0":"0","catid":"0","1":"650","value":"650","2":"650 euro","description":"650 euro"},{"0":"1","catid":"1","1":"0","value":"0","2":"No","description":"No"},{"0":"1","catid":"1","1":"1","value":"1","2":"Yes","description":"Yes"}])
```

Now what i want is to use the JSON to fill select boxes, just like you would in HTML:

```
<select id="0">
    <option value="350">350 euro</option>
    <option value="500">500 euro</option>
    <option value="650">650 euro</option>
</select>

<select id="1">
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone help me with this? I know how to do a loop to fill a table (with $.getJSON), but i'm kinda stuck with this one.

Comment: by the json parsing you should have to make a parser and by if and else condition on addcat you will be able to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will loop through your posted object and populate the menus (given your posted source):

```
var populateSelects = function(data) {
    var cat0 = $('select#0'),
        cat1 = $('select#1'),
        opt = $('<option />'),
        newOpt = {},
        cat0opts = [],
        cat1opts = [];
    $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
        //clone the option element so as to not re-create a new one
        newOpt = opt.clone();
        //obj is the JavaScript object in the array, so
        //dot-notation works nicely
        newOpt.text(obj.description).val(obj.value);
        if (obj.catid === "0") {
            //push the DOM element, not the jQuery object
            cat0opts.push(newOpt[0]);
        } else if (obj.catid === "1") {
            cat1opts.push(newOpt[0]);
        }
    });
    //Add the array of DOM elements to their respective menus,
    //clearing out any existing menu items.
    cat0.empty().append(cat0opts);
    cat1.empty().append(cat1opts);
};
```

Here's a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/a5MTE/1/

One note of importance is the `catid` comparison... if the parsed JSON returns `catid` as  number (not a string) you'll want to change the comparison to `if (obj.catid === 0)`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for taking time to write this.

Answer (score 0):

by the json parsing you should have to make a parser and by if and else condition on addcat you will be able to do it